# Notification is trigger after boot automatically in Android

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

I'm new to Android developer and I have a problem with my app. I created a custom `BroadcastReceiver`, but when I start my app, this is running my notification automatically. I don't want this Notification running until my AlarmManager schedule starts.

**I really need help, because this app is my term paper.**

Here are my codes:

Notification Receiver:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String cnh_vencida;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("ALARME_DISPAROU")) {

            Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
            cnh_vencida = context.getString(R.string.cnh_vencimento);

            PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, CadastroUser.class), 0);

            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                    .setTicker("teste")
                    .setCategory(Notification.CATEGORY_ALARM)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.car)
                    .setContentTitle("CarMaintenance")
                    .setContentText(cnh_vencida)
                    .setContentIntent(pi)
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setSound(uri)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000})
                    .build();
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

        }
    }
}
```

Part of my AndroidManifest

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".notification.AlarmReceiver"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver
        android:name=".notification.NotificationReceiver"
        android:exported="false"
        android:enabled="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="ALARME_DISPAROU" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

AlarmReceiver (if the user restarts your device, this class will reschedules the alarm)

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String dataValidade;
    Date date;
    String CATEGORIA;

    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {
            recreateAlert(context);
        }
    }

    public void recreateAlert(Context context) {

        CadastroUserDAO cadastroUserDAO = new CadastroUserDAO(context);

        List<CadastroUserModel> registros;
        registros = cadastroUserDAO.listarTodos();
        if (registros.size() > 0) {
            Log.i(CATEGORIA, "Existe CNH Cadastrada");

            for (int i = 0; i < registros.size(); i++) {
                dataValidade = (registros.get(i).getVALIDADE_CNH());
            }

            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            try {
                date = simpleDateFormat.parse(dataValidade);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(date);
            calendar.add(calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -45);

            AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            Intent alarmIntent = new Intent("ALARME_DISPAROU");
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
            alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 5, pendingIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did my answer work for you? Consider accepting it if yes

Answer (score 0):

One of the options is to get rid of the `<intent-filter>` and specify the `NotificationReceiver` directly in intent.

in Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".notification.NotificationReceiver" />
```

in AlarmReceiver:

```
AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, alarmIntent, 0);
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY * 5, pendingIntent);
```

And remove `if` statement in NotificationReceiver file.